# Differences between real and complex analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

To start with, real analysis deals with numbers along the (one dimensional) number line, while complex analysis deals with numbers along two dimensions, real and imaginary, Cartesian style. Could this be what causes some of the differences mentioned below?

For instance real analysis deals with sequences of numbers, while complex analysis deals with series, which is the say, the sums of terms of sequences. Real analysis seems to be about limits and accumulation points and oriented toward differentiation, while complex analysis deals with with curve integrals and radii of convergence, and "poles," lending itself more to integration.

Is complex analysis to real analysis what polar coordinates are to linear coordinates, and does this help explain the differences in their orientations?

Comment: To some slightly ironic extent, the difference is that both are one dimensional.

Comment: I learned about sequences, limits, and series in both real *and* complex analysis as an undergraduate.  In many analysis books (in particular graduate level I suppose) we work in completely arbitrary spaces (with varying requirements, e.g. metric spaces, banach spaces, sigma algebras) and the results can be applied to $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ or whatever space we are in.

Comment: I would say your impressions are not correct, sequences, series, derivatives, integrals, limits, are the fundamental building blocks of analysis and to my mind real and complex analysis deal with them about equally.  I find a lot of real analysis makes critical use of the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is totally ordered, $\mathbb{C}$ loses order but gains a lot of 'elegant' properties such as well behaved derivatives, algebraic closure, etc.

Comment: @Tyroshipleasurebarge: " ℝ is totally ordered, ℂ loses order but gains a lot of 'elegant' properties such as well behaved derivatives, algebraic closure, etc." That was the kind of response I was hoping to get. Perhaps you could expand your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best way to explain the difference, as I get it, is that the meaning of a derivative in complex analysis is much, much more restrictive than that in real analysis. This gives complex-differentiable functions much more structure than their counterparts in real analysis.

This can be thought to have something to do with having more dimensions. In particular, 2D geometry has more structure than 1D. To understand just how they are "much more restrictive" geometrically, we can think of a differentiable real function to be one that looks, on a small scale, like a "stretch" of the line around that area. But a complex-differentiable function on the plane has to actually look like a *shape-preserving transformation* in a small area. It cannot stretch (irregularly), reflect, or otherwise change shapes. It can only change scale or rotate. Much more information is required to be preserved, and this makes the functions more restricted and mathematically *more interesting*. In general, the more rules your widgets have to follow, the more interesting they tend to be.

More formally, a general 2D differentiable function from the 2D plane to the 2D plane is one where its partial derivatives all exist everywhere, so we have a Jacobian matrix. To be complex-differentiable, we essentially *add* the requirement that this matrix looks like a matrix representation of a complex number. (The equations on the partial derivatives that this gives are the Cauchy-Riemann equations.) This complex number is the function's complex derivative.

Sequences in the complex numbers aren't much different from real numbers: they can be thought of as just pairs of real numbers. In particular, there is nothing magic about convergence, limits, etc. of sequences of elements of $\mathbb{C}$ versus those of elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$. In this sense there isn't as much "new" to get in sequence stuff. The new stuff really comes from differentiable functions and the much more restrictive definition of complex derivative. The thing that sets the complex numbers apart from just plain old pairs of real numbers is their multiplication operation, which entangles the real and imaginary components together. And it is in the derivative where this operation is exploited, by the division by the complex increment $\Delta z$. In addition, a limit of *a complex function*, which is what the difference quotient is, as opposed to the limit of a *sequence, is also* more restrictive, since we have far more "angles of attack" we have to account for in 2 dimensions instead of in 1 dimension.

Comment: I learned real analysis and complex analysis during my undergraduate. My lecturer asked me to compare the results in both of them Complex analysis mainly focus on analytic functions. There are one MAIN difference between real and complex analysis. In real analysis, if you can differentiate a function one times, there is NO guarantee you can differentiate it second times (the counterexample leave it to the reader). But, in complex analysis, if a complex-valued function is analytic, then you can differentiate it infinitely many times.

Comment: @measure2012: That's right. That's one of those things that falls under "having a lot more structure". And there's so many other structural results as well, e.g. the two Picard theorems, Liouville's theorem, the theorem that an injective entire function is linear, the non-existence of bump functions, etc.

Comment: what means by "having a lot more structure"? Just want to share information about  Liouville's theorem(LT) you say above. By using LT, one can show that sin z and cos z are unbounded functions in complex plane. But in real analysis, sin x and cos x are bounded functions. This is another difference between real and complex.

Comment: "More structure" means things have more and more interesting properties.